# RangeError, Syntax error: invalid regular expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

## Hi,

#### I've been following [this tutorial](http://sahatyalkabov.com/create-a-tv-show-tracker-using-angularjs-nodejs-and-mongodb/) on the Mean Stack.

However, past the step 7 I've found myself struggle with an error which I cannot solve.

When trying to get the route **"/shows/:id"**, Chrome stumbles across a loop of error and doesn't do anything:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\d+$/: Stack overflow
```

Mozilla gives the following error message when freezing upon the same action:

```
[invalid object] <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

I'm not sure what sample of code I should copy here since I've followed every step of the tutorial and checked for any error.

However, I've used the TMDB api instead of the one proposed by the tutorial, and made some adjustments.

#### This is the server and the routing code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var _ = require('lodash');

// MONGOOSE
var showSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: Number,
  name: String,
  createdBy: String,
  nextEpisodeToAir: String,
  airsTime: String,
  firstAired: Date,
  genre: [String],
  network: String,
  overview: String,
  rating: Number,
  ratingCount: Number,
  status: String,
  poster: String,
  subscribers: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'
  }],
  seasonsCount: Number,
  episodesCount: Number,
  episodes: [{
    season: Number,
    episodeNumber: Number,
    episodeName: String,
    firstAired: Date,
    overview: String
  }]
});

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  password: String
});

userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;
  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});

// compare passwords
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb(null, isMatch);
  });
};

// models
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var Show = mongoose.model('Show', showSchema);

// connect
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/shows', {useNewUrlParser: true});

var app = express();

app
    .set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)
    .use(logger('dev'))
    .use(bodyParser.json())
    .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
    .use(cookieParser())
    .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// REST routes
app.get('/api/shows', function(req, res, next) {
  var query = Show.find();
  if (req.query.genre) {
    query.where({genre: req.query.genre});
  } else if (req.query.alphabet) {
    query.where({name: new RegExp('^' + '[' + req.query.alphabet + ']', 'i')});
  } else {
    query.limit(12);
  }
  query.exec(function(err, shows) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.send(shows);
  });
});

app.get('/api/shows/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Show.findById(req.params.id, function(err, show) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.send(show);
  });
});

app.post('/api/shows', function(req, res, next) {
  //themoviedb.org API
  const apiKey = 'c230f35fe557299c704ef84fe35aa8fa';
  const urlTMDB = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/';  
/*
    1. Get the Show ID given the Show Name and pass it on to the next function.
    2. Get the show information using the Show ID from previous step and pass the new show object on to the next function.
    3. Convert the poster image to Base64, assign it to show.poster and pass the show object to the final callback function.
    4. Save the show object to database.
*/
    async.waterfall([
      function(cb) {
        // Get the show ID
 
        let options = {
          method: 'GET',
          url: urlTMDB + 'search/tv',
          qs: {
            query: req.body.showName,
            api_key: apiKey
          },
          body: '{}'
        };
    
        request(options, function(err, res, body) {
          if (err) throw new Error(err);
          let data = JSON.parse(body);
          // console.log(data.total_results);
          if(data.total_results === 0) {
            return req.res.status(404).send({message: req.body.showName + ' was not found.'});
          }
          let seriesId = data.results[0].id;
          // console.log('id:' + seriesId);
          cb(err, seriesId);
        });
      },
      function(seriesId, cb) {

        // Get Show info
        let options = {
          method: 'GET',
          url: urlTMDB + 'tv/' + seriesId,
          qs: {api_key: apiKey},
          body: '{}'
        }

        request(options, function(err, res, body) {
          if (err) throw new Error(err);
          let data = JSON.parse(body);
          // Creating genres array because don't know how to fix this inline
          let genres = [];
          data.genres.forEach(g => {
            genres.push(g.name);
          });
          let show = new Show({
            _id: data.id,
            name: data.original_name,
            createdBy: data.created_by,
            nextEpisodeToAir: data.next_episode_to_air,
            airsTime: data.episode_run_time,
            firstAired: data.first_air_date,
            genre: genres,
            network: data.networks[0].name,
            overview: data.overview,
            rating: data.vote_average,
            ratingCount: data.vote_count,
            status: data.status,
            poster: 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/' + data.poster_path,
            seasonsCount: data.number_of_seasons,
            episodesCount: data.number_of_episodes
          });
          // console.log(show);
          cb(err, seriesId, show);
        });
      },
      function(err, show) {
        show.save(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            if (err.code == 11000) {
              return res.status(409).send({message: show.name + ' already exists.'});
            }
            return next(err);
          }
          res.sendStatus(200);
        });
      }
    ]);
  });

// handles bad routes and redirect
// using * (wild card)
// KEEP THIS ATER ALL OTHER ROUTES

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/#' + req.originalUrl);
});



// Stack trace of errors
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send({message: err.message});
});


app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

#### And this is my details controller:

```js
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('DetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', 'Show', 'Subscription', 
        function($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, Show, Subscription) {
            Show.get({_id: $routeParams.id}, function(show) {
                $scope.show = show;

                $scope.isSubscribed = function() {
                    return $scope.show.subscribers.indexOf($rootScope.currentUser._id) !== -1;
                };

                $scope.subscribe = function() {
                    Subscription.subscribe(show).success(function() {
                        $scope.show.subscribers.push($rootScope.currentUser._id);
                    });
                };

                $scope.unsubscribe = function() {
                    Subscription.unsubscribe(show).success(function() {
                        let index = $scope.show.subscribers.indexOf($rootScope.currentUser._id);
                        $scope.show.subscribers.splice(index, 1);
                    });
                };


                
                $scope.nextEpisode = show.episodes.filter(function(episode0) {
                    return new Date(episode.firstAired) > new Date();
                })[0];


            });
    }]);
```

Hoping for a bit of clarity with this problem :/
Thank you all for the help!

Comment: you said you're accessing `/show/:id` but shouldn't be `/shows/:id` ?
Also, have you tried cleaning cache and reloading the page? What about other browsers? (I'm asking this coz you mentioned Chrome in a way that makes me think that in other browsers is working fine, just wanna clarify)

Comment: thx @adoltotcar, i corrected my error in the description, it's trully "/shows/:d" that i'm accessing.
About the browser, mozilla gives me this error message: 

[invalid object] <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">

Then, clearing cache doesn't help :/

Answer (score -1):

Holy cow, I feel so stupid.

The mozilla error message disturbed me because it pointed to the view code.
When checking my module code, I found that I made a typo in the name of the view that should be used when accessing to **/shows/:id**.

Everything works properly now. Sorry for the disturbance :)